# Eclipse is giving an error when trying to refactor a method's signature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt, spring-ide

Whenever I try to change a method's signature using eclipse refactoring functionality (shortcut Shift+Alt+c) I get an error dialog with the text below.

```
An unexpected exception occured while performing the refactoring. See the error log for more details 
org/springframework/ide/eclipse/ui/editor/util/BeansEditorUtils


!ENTRY org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 4 10000 2013-10-03 12:25:20.295
```

!MESSAGE Internal Error

!STACK 0

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)

at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.run(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:331)

at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.internalPerformFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:637)

at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.UserInputWizardPage.performFinish(UserInputWizardPage.java:153)

at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.performFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:710)

at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.okPressed(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:455)

at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:472)

at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)

at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)

at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)

at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:187)

at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)

at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:202)

at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.RefactoringStarter.activate(RefactoringStarter.java:38)
```

/// many more lines removed

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.editor.Activator for bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.editor is invalid

```
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)

at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)

at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)

at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)

at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)

at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)

... 133 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/springframework/ide/eclipse/beans/ui/editor/Activator, method: getTemplateStore signature: ()Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/templates/persistence/TemplateStore;) Bad type in putfield/putstatic

```
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)

at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
```

I'm running the following version of eclipse: 
Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722

looking at the "for more details" it sounds that the error could be caused by the SpringIDE plugin. I have the version: 3.3.0.201307091516-RELEASE

If you need me to provide additional details please ask and tell me where I could find them.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Look in the error log view (Window / Show View /  Error Log) or look at the `.log` file in the workspace `.metadata` directory.

Comment: @greg-449, thanks a lot, I updated the question with the log's stack trace error, it's definitely the Spring IDE

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to Eclipse bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=268226 which suggests restarting Eclipse specifying the `-clean` option.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. The bug you're referring to seem to affect CDT, the one I'm seeing is in SpringIDE. I know a -clean could fix many stuff, unfortunately it didn't fix mine...